# Does order by lock the entire table if the order of row have clustered index in posgres?

Tags: postgresql

Imagine the following query

```
SELECT id, data from table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```

with the following schema

```
id int clusterindex, primary index
data text
```

Essentially I want to get the max id in the table, if I put this statement in a transaction, does it lock the entire table due to the usage of order by?

I am using clusterIndex because I want O(1) select for the max or min id

Comment: SELECT never locks anything. And Postgres does not have clustered indexes to begin with

Comment: i mean select in a transaction so if there is any update it should lock? also pgadmin shows clustered as one of the option during index creation https://imgur.com/a/r3U3ZgI , I am surprised that does nothing

Comment: Again: a SELECT won't lock anything (unless you include `for update`). The table maybe "clustered" along the index, but that's not the same as a "clustered index" (as e.g. there is in SQL Server)

Comment: I am putting the select with update in a transaction, does it not lock during update? whats the difference between a table that is clustered along the index vs clustered index? I thought both mean the row are sorted by the index physically when stored

Comment: Please review [Migrate your mindset too](https://blog.sql-workbench.eu/post/migrate-your-mindset/).  MS SQL Server and Postgres are apparently using the same term for a different concept.

Comment: It's unclear to me if you do use `select ... for update` or if you are running an `update` after you selected the row. But in any case, even a `select .. for update` only locks the rows that are returned by the query, not the whole table.

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL does not have a clustered index (`CLUSTER` rewrites the table once in index order, but that order is not maintained), and there are no “read locks” in PostgreSQL.

Your query will not lock anything (except that it places an `ACCESS SHARE` table lock on the table to prevent things like a concurrent `DROP TABLE`), and it does not need an explicit sort if you have an index on `id`.

There is no performance advantage in `CLUSTER`ing the table for this query, since it returns only a single row.